# Perl DBI execute multiple SQL queries at once

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I need to execute 2 mysql queries at once to find the position number of element in query,like:

```
SET @v1 := 0;  select tbl.number,tbl.name  from (select @v1:=(@v1+1) AS number, id, name,aps from acc order by aps desc limit 5) as tbl where tbl.name='jetli';
```

But DBI doesn't allow to put 2 queries at once.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, [user-defined variables are session-specific.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) You can set a variable in one statement and access it in a later one:

```
$dbh->do('SET @foo := 0');

my ($result) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT @foo');
print $result;
# 0
```